# Apache Linux Server bind with ADS

Tags: linux, apache, binding, ads

Actually I want to run apache server in which user must be authenticate via ADS (Active directory) server. Apache server must be run on Linux OS and ADS works on Windows Server 2003 R2.
For creating communication between Apache and ADS we need bind between via LDAP. 
I am trying to bind them..but still there is some problem.
Can you help me and tell me exact steps which I need to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [mod_auth_sspi](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Thank you for your posting But ...first I want to bind Linux and Windows via LDAP. So, if I run query in Linux (Like - LDAPSEARCH) so it must take input from ADS and then provide answer. Can you help me for this.